# Standard error and estimating intervals

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, standard-error

I've been teaching myself some statistics and upon doing this problem I've stumbled at the very last part:

[image: Statistics problem]

I've had no problem reaching $\mu\approx x=220.1$ and $\sigma\approx y= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}$, which agrees with the solution document. I then reasoned that if I wanted an interval of 2 standard errors around the estimated mean, that would just be $x\pm2\cdot\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}}=220.1\pm\frac{1}{5}$, but this is apparently incorrect.

The correct calculation of 2 standard errors around the mean is shown as $220.1\pm2\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}=220.1\pm\frac{2}{5}$. Can you help me figure out why they have multiplied by a factor of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ instead?

(A picture of the solutions I've been using are [here](https://ibb.co/TbnYpG6) and [here](https://ibb.co/rpkhprB))

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat \mu = \frac45T+\frac15(T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4)$ has expectation $\mu$ and variance $\frac45 \sigma^2$

$\hat \sigma^2 =(\frac1{\sqrt{5}}T-\frac1{\sqrt{5}}(T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4))^2$ has expectation $\sigma^2$, so $\frac45 \hat \sigma^2$ has expectation $\frac45  \sigma^2$

So it seems a reasonable confidence interval is $\hat \mu \pm k\sqrt{\frac45\hat \sigma^2}$ which here is $220.1 \pm k\sqrt{\frac45 \times  (-\frac1{\sqrt{5}} 0.5)^2}= 220.1 \pm 0.2 k$, and for $k=2$ is $220.1 \pm 0.4$ i.e. $[219.7, 220.5]$